# Which results via algebraic or direct manipulations of divergent series can be rigorously justified and why?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I thought that if you try and calculate the sum $1+2+3+\dots$ in any "reasonable" way, you should get $\frac{-1}{12}$. One example of such a manipulation is in the Mathologer video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcKRGpMiVTw&list=PL-LSf4Q-q_0s7dF7MHmnEtN5N8YeYNCw1&index=6&t=363s. Another example: https://medium.com/cantors-paradise/the-ramanujan-summation-1-2-3-1-12-a8cc23dea793

This produces the same answer as the analytic continuation of the Reimann Zeta function and many other methods. However, I just found a route that shows it's $\frac{-1}{8}$. Let:

$$s=1+2^2+3^2+\dots$$
$$4s=2^2+2^2 2^2+2^2 3^3+\dots$$

Subtracting,

$$-3s = 1+3^2+5^2+7^2+\dots$$
Shifting one term to the left:
$$-3s = 1+3^2+5^2+\dots$$

Subtracting:

$$0=1+2 \times4+2 \times8+2\times12 +\dots=1+8(1+2+3+\dots)$$

$$=> 1+2+3+\dots = \frac{-1}{8}$$

Where did I go wrong where the others didn't?

Comment: There's a typo in the last term of $4s$.

Comment: You are doing manipulations with a divergent series as if it is a convergent series. That's a problem.

Comment: That $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$ is a _much_ more intricate result than doing arithmetic with divergent sums. Simply put you can’t just play around with divergent sums like this - you can get any value you want for the sum with enough work by playing around enough.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik the even-indexed terms of $s=1+2^2+3^2+\dots+(2k)^2+(2k+1)^2+\dots$ correspond to the terms of $4s=2^2+(2\cdot 2)^2 + (2\cdot 3)^2+\dots$ and so the subtraction effectively removes all even-indexed terms, leaving only the odd-indexed terms

Comment: @csch2 - Mathologer does it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcKRGpMiVTw&list=PL-LSf4Q-q_0s7dF7MHmnEtN5N8YeYNCw1&index=6&t=363s. Are you saying he "shouldn't have" done it? Why is his result consistent with the continuation of Reimann Zeta while mine not?

Comment: You might consider rephrasing this question as something like “which results via algebraic or direct manipulations of divergent series can be rigorously justified and why?” because otherwise, as it is now, the (pedantic) answer to the question “where did I go wrong?” with respect to manipulating the divergent series is “the beginning!”.

Comment: @NapD.Lover - great suggestion. Edited the title.

Comment: Check this out: https://brilliant.org/wiki/sums-of-divergent-series/

Answer (score 4):

The error becomes evident when you consider the analogous finite sum.

Let $$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^2.$$  Then following your logic,
$$4S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2,$$ and $$-3S(n) = S(n) - 4S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - (2k)^2.$$  When we perform the cancellation of the even terms, the first sum becomes $$\sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} (2j-1)^2$$ as you expect, but the number of terms that are cancelled in the second sum is not the entire sum:  what is left over is $$\sum_{j=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor+1}^{n} (2j)^2.$$  So $$-3S(n) = \sum_{j=1}^{\lceil n/2 \rceil} (2j-1)^2 - \sum_{j=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor + 1}^n (2j)^2.$$  Then you shift the summation index by $1$ and perform more calculations.  For the sake of clarity, assume $n = 2m$ is even, so that we have
$$-3S(2m) = \sum_{j=1}^m (2j-1)^2 - \sum_{j=m+1}^{2m} (2j)^2,$$
consequently your shift and subtraction becomes
$$\begin{align*}
0
&\overset{?}{=} 3S(2(m+1)) - 1 - 3S(2m) \\
&= \left( \sum_{j=2}^{m+1} (2j-1)^2 - \sum_{j=m+2}^{2m+2} (2j)^2 \right) - \left(\sum_{j=1}^m (2j-1)^2 - \sum_{j=m+1}^{2m} (2j)^2\right) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^m (2j+1)^2 - (2j-1)^2 \\
& \quad - \left((2(2m+2))^2 + (2(2m+1))^2 - (2(m+1))^2 \right) \\
&= 8\sum_{j=1}^m j - (28m^2 + 40m + 16).
\end{align*}$$
And here now is where you see that your reasoning fails, because this remainder term is quadratically increasing in $m$, and is not vanishing as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I want summation methods that will be consistent with the analytic continuation methods of the Reimann Zeta function. If I applied your reasoning to the $1+2+3+\dots = -\frac{1}{12}$ summation, would I still see this kind of "problem"?